# working example of phonegap android integration with third party api

Tags: android, api, cordova

i'm new at phonegap. any guide or example of the process of linking an api such as http://openweathermap.org/. want to get data from this api on android app

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery mobile to parse data from any API.
Follow the code and example JSON given below.

```
$.getJSON('ajax/test.json', function(data) {
  var items = [];

  $.each(data, function(key, val) {
    items.push('<li id="' + key + '">' + val + '</li>');
  });

  $('<ul/>', {
    'class': 'my-new-list',
    html: items.join('')
  }).appendTo('body');
});

This example, of course, relies on the structure of the JSON file:

{
  "one": "Singular sensation",
  "two": "Beady little eyes",
  "three": "Little birds pitch by my doorstep"
}
```

Comment: Sanawaj thanks for answering but it wasn't of much use to me because i didn't get it, consider me an absolute beginner im in learning phase, can you post the method for requesting data from api, specifically ajax request method, i have mentioned the website above already

Comment: You've to follow jQuery Mobile tutorials.I'm giving you some link.You can also use above method pass your URL in the place of 'ajax/test.json'.

Comment: thanks Sanawaj waiting for links. Actually i have figured out from your answer and some googling that what i need is basically a $get request to the API which will append my parameters of city code and APPID to the apis Url and fetch the results back, now trying how to do that

Comment: follow the flicker example